# Terraform Custom provider, is it possible read an attribute value from main.tf rather state while destroy?

Tags: terraform

We have a custom home grown terraform provider.
Which has func resourceIamCreate, func resourceIamDelete etc.
While performing the create (func resourceIamCreate), it takes the attribute(change_ticket) value from the main.tf file and state get updated with value of attribute change_ticket.

When perform destroy (func resourceIamDelete), it reads the value of change_ticket from state rather from our main.tf file.

Is there a way we can make delete read the value of change_ticket from main.tf file?

Thanks.

Comment: We really need to see a MVCE, but also why would you want to use the config attribute instead of the state attribute during a `Delete`? This sounds a lot like the provider will target the wrong resource with the API bindings.

Comment: Because, the change_ticket at the time of deploy do have specific window of start and end time.

If you are doing delete after that window, our api (which is used by the custom provider) will complain that you are doing delete outside change window.

So we have to have the ability to pass new change ticket which will have an active window.

Comment: No, it runs against the state. https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/aws-destroy. "The terraform destroy command terminates resources managed by your Terraform project. This command is the inverse of terraform apply in that it terminates all the resources specified in your Terraform state."

Comment: That would be an issue with the API that should really be fixed in the API instead of a workaround in the provider that would possibly cause an incorrectly targeted endpoint.

Comment: Actually its not api issue. A change ticket (service now) will always have a window.
And actions (deploy, destroy) should only be performed during that window.
For deploy, some one would have used change ticket.
And later a month he decided to destroy, and obviously, the original change ticket is no longer valid as the window is over. So he/she should be using a new valid change ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

I rebuilt the provider after moving change_ticket as provider input in provider.go and now I can pass change_ticket to destroy